# Does Openssl 1.1.1 library supports sending multiple identities as part of PSK?

Tags: encryption, tls, openssl

Does Openssl 1.1.1 supports sending multiple ticket identities as part of PSK? i have gone through the openssl code and i don't see that openssl supports it. could someone please confirm it if i missing something there?